# Time difference between recorded video file and CountDownTimer in android

Tags: android, countdowntimer, android-mediarecorder, android-video-player, video-recording

I am trying to implement video recorder with timer. 
My recording start when I start `CountDownTimer` and I gave maximum time limit to 30 seconds. So after 30 seconds `onFinish()` method will be called. And in `onFinish()` method I stopped video recording. So ideally recorded video should be of 30 seconds. ***But now when I open recorded video ,it is not of 30 seconds. It is 28 seconds.There is a difference of 2 seconds in timer and recorder.*** So can you please help me with this problem ?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;


public class VideoRecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    @BindView(R.id.ivRecord)
    ImageView ivRecord;
    @BindView(R.id.ivChangeCamera)
    ImageView ivChangeCamera;
    private Context myContext;
    private LinearLayout cameraPreview;
    private boolean cameraFront = false;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private TextView tvTimer;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private boolean isStarted;
    @BindView(R.id.tvTotalTimer)
    TextView tvTotalTimer;
    public static final int VIDEO_TRIMMER_REQUEST_CODE = 1010;
    private Random random;
    private String randomVideoFileName = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
    private String videoRecordingPath;
    int AUDIO_RECORD_LIMIT_MILLI_SECOND = 30000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_record);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        random = new Random();
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        myContext = this;
        initialize();
    }


    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        }
        if (mCamera == null) {
            // if the front facing camera does not exist
            if (findFrontFacingCamera() < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ivChangeCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mCamera = Camera.open(findBackFacingCamera());
            setCameraOritentation(mCamera);
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // when on Pause, release camera in order to be used from other
        // applications
        releaseCamera();
    }

    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    private int findBackFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the back facing camera
        // get the number of cameras
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        // for every camera check
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        cameraPreview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
        cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);

        ivRecord.setOnClickListener(this);

        ivChangeCamera.setOnClickListener(this);

        tvTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
        tvTotalTimer.setText("" + CommonUtilities.milliSecondsToTimer(AUDIO_RECORD_LIMIT_MILLI_SECOND - 1000));

        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        mSeekBar.setMax(30);
        mSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return true;
            }
        });


        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (!isStarted) {

                    isStarted = true;
                }

                int timeRemaining = (int) ((AUDIO_RECORD_LIMIT_MILLI_SECOND / 1000) - (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                mSeekBar.setProgress(timeRemaining);
                tvTimer.setText("" + CommonUtilities.milliSecondsToTimer(AUDIO_RECORD_LIMIT_MILLI_SECOND - millisUntilFinished));

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                tvTimer.setText("" + CommonUtilities.milliSecondsToTimer(AUDIO_RECORD_LIMIT_MILLI_SECOND - 1000));
                mSeekBar.setProgress(AUDIO_RECORD_LIMIT_MILLI_SECOND / 1000);
                onRecordingStopped(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            }
        };
    }

    public void chooseCamera() {
        // if the camera preview is the front
        if (cameraFront) {
            int cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId >= 0) {
                // open the backFacingCamera
                // set a picture callback
                // refresh the preview

                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                setCameraOritentation(mCamera);
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        } else {
            int cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId >= 0) {
                // open the backFacingCamera
                // set a picture callback
                // refresh the preview

                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                setCameraOritentation(mCamera);
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
        // check if the device has camera
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    boolean recording = false;

    private void onRecordingStopped() {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            isStarted = false;
            ivChangeCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ivRecord.clearAnimation();
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use

            Toast.makeText(VideoRecordActivity.this, "Video captured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            recording = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(VideoRecordActivity.this, TrimmerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("path", videoRecordingPath);
            startActivityForResult(intent,VIDEO_TRIMMER_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == VIDEO_TRIMMER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        if (!cameraFront) {
            if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
                mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
            }
            if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
                mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(180);
            }
        } else {
            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
            {
                mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
            }
        }

        mCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        //mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoRecordingPath);
        //mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(10000000); // Set max file size 50M

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            onRecordingStopped();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            onRecordingStopped();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        // stop and release camera
        if (mCamera != null) {

            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }


    private void setCameraOritentation(Camera mCamera) {

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.ivRecord:
                if (recording) {
                    // stop recording and release camera
                    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                    onRecordingStopped(); // release the MediaRecorder object


                } else {
                    if (!new File(LOCAL_VIDEO_STORAGE_DIRECTORY_PATH).exists())
                        new File(LOCAL_VIDEO_STORAGE_DIRECTORY_PATH).mkdirs();

                    videoRecordingPath = LOCAL_VIDEO_STORAGE_DIRECTORY_PATH +
                            CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + "VideoRecording.mp4";
                    if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
                        Toast.makeText(VideoRecordActivity.this, "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }


                    try {
                        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(VideoRecordActivity.this, R.anim.rotateimage);
                        rotation.setFillAfter(true);
                        ivRecord.startAnimation(rotation);
                        ivChangeCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        mediaRecorder.start();
                        mCountDownTimer.start();
                    } catch (final Exception ex) {
                        // Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
                    }


                    /*// work on UiThread for better performance
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // If there are stories, add them to the table

                            try {
                                Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(VideoRecordActivity.this, R.anim.rotateimage);
                                rotation.setFillAfter(true);
                                ivRecord.startAnimation(rotation);

                                ivChangeCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mCountDownTimer.start();
                            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                                // Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
                            }
                        }
                    });*/

                    recording = true;
                }
                break;

            case R.id.ivChangeCamera:
                if (!recording) {
                    int camerasNumber = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
                    if (camerasNumber > 1) {
                        // release the old camera instance
                        // switch camera, from the front and the back and vice versa

                        releaseCamera();
                        chooseCamera();
                    } else {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone has only one camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    public String CreateRandomAudioFileName(int string) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(string);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < string) {
            stringBuilder.append(randomVideoFileName.
                    charAt(random.nextInt(randomVideoFileName.length())));

            i++;
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `prepareMediaRecorder()` on `onCreate` ? Could it be the delay until the camera is prepared to record?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Can't do that because I have initialized mCamera in onResume(). So it will throw null pointer exception if i call prepareMediaRecorder() on onCreate. Any other solution? And if you have any ready demo of video recording with seekbar and timer then that will be good.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I think when we call mCountDownTimer.start(); then timer start immediately but when we call mediaRecorder.start(); mediarecorder taking 2-3 second to start a recording that's why timer end at 30 seconds still your video length is 28-29 seconds.